# How to add a column in a Dataset, with a variable value (int) for each row

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, dataset

I have a Dataset I get from my MySQL Databasen using a method from my WCF Service. This Dataset contains the list of the projects in my database.
It's a list of the projects, displayed like this :

ID | Name

1 | Toast

(this is an example)

I want to add, in the end of the dataset, a new column, like this :

ID | Name | Status

1 | Toast | 1

I have another method that returns an int. For parameters, this method take the ID of a projet. For example, the id of Toast is 1. So I enter my method with the parameter 1. You see what I mean ?

So I have a dataset that contains this :

ID | Name

1 | Toast

and an int that contains this :
1

so, I want to add a new row, based on the ID of the project.
Keep in mind I can have MANY others projects, so I need to check any row..

I don't know how to proceed...
Thanks for your help.

Comment: First add a new column to the DataTable and then add values to the new row.  A DataSet consists of one or more DataTables.

Answer (score 0):

Already answered here:

[Add new column and data to datatable that already contains data - c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312966/add-new-column-and-data-to-datatable-that-already-contains-data-c-sharp#2313125)

```
DataTable dt = sql.ExecuteDataTable("sp_MyProc");    
dt.Columns.Add("Status", typeof(System.Int32));    
foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    row["Status"] = GetStatus(row["ID"]);
```

A full example

```
void Main()
{   
    //setup 
    DataSet projects = new DataSet("ProjectsDataSet");
    projects.Tables.Add(new DataTable("ProjectsTable"));

    DataTable ProjectsDataTable = projects.Tables["ProjectsTable"]; 

    ProjectsDataTable.Columns.Add("id", typeof(Int32));
    ProjectsDataTable.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));

    var row1 = ProjectsDataTable.NewRow();
    row1["id"] = 1;
    row1["name"] = "some project name";
    ProjectsDataTable.Rows.Add(row1);

    //you are here

    //add a column
    ProjectsDataTable.Columns.Add("status", typeof(Int32));

    //populate column
    foreach (DataRow row in ProjectsDataTable.Rows) {
        row["status"] = 123;        
    }

    projects.Dump(); // shows result, only works in linqpad 
}
```

Comment: No, it's for datatables. My code works with Dataset. "How to add a column in a Dataset" Not "How to add a column in a Datatable"

Comment: A DataSet contains DataTabes. DataTabes have columns and data.

Comment: I have added a full example to my answer.